# How to perform a Html.ValidationSummary in an ajax submit?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I do not know why is not working the `ValidationSummary` when I perform a `Html.BeginForm` using `AJAX.submit`.

```
@model Contoso.MvcApplication.Models.Questions.MultipleChoiceQuestionTemplate

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditQuestion", "Question", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "editQuestionForm" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorForModel("Questions/_MultipleChoiceQuestion")

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
}

    public class MultipleChoiceQuestionTemplate : QuestionTemplate, IValidatableObject
    {
        public MultipleChoiceQuestionTemplate() { ... }

        [DisplayName("Question")]
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public List<string> Choices { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Correct Choice")]
        public int CorrectChoice { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Choices5[CorrectChoice]))
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("ERROR");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my jquery submit function:

```
            $("#editQuestionForm").submit(function () {
                if ($(this).valid()) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: this.action,
                        type: this.method,
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#result').html(result);
                        }
                    });
                }

                return false;
            });
```

But I'm something something, because as you can see above, I've implemented `ValidatableObject` interface and when I click the submit button, perform a post when my validation models has errors and should display the error in the `ValidationSummary`.

Comment: _"I'm something something"_ ? ~  Please clarify the language of your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to worry about a `submit` handler since the jQuery Validate plugin already has the **submit event handler callback function built in, and this is exactly where you are *supposed* to put your ajax.**

[As per the documentation for the Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), the `submitHandler` callback function is:

> "Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets
>   the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. **The right
>   place to submit a form via Ajax** after it validated."

Try this code instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#yourform").validate({
        // rules & options,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                    url: form.action,
                    type: form.method,
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#result').html(result);
                    }
            });
            return false; // blocks redirect after submission via ajax
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/sx26b/**